# Javascript play and pause a song with one click on the same image

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Hi im trying to have a song play when i click and pause when i click it again however it only seems to be playing this is the code below:

Javascript

```
 function StartOrStop(audioFile)
  {
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    if(!audie.src) 
       audie.src = audioFile;
    if(audie.paused == false)
     {
        audie.pause();
     }
     else
     {
       audie.play();
     }
  }
```

HTML5

```
<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button width="57" height="50" onclick="StartOrStop('RWY.mp3')" >
```

Any suggestion on how i can fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

When ever you click the `image`, it calls the `StartOrStop` function, this will cause the `src` of video set again thus cause `paused` to be `true` so you can't pause the video but just play it again.

This version should work:

#### HTML:

```
<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button" width="57" height="50" onclick="StartOrStop('RWY.mp3')">

<audio id="myAudio"></audio>
```

#### Javascript:

```
function StartOrStop(audioFile) {
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    if (!audie.src || audie.src !== audioFile) audie.src = audioFile; // check if there's a src already and if the current src is not the same with the new one, change it. Or don't do anything.
    if (audie.paused == false)
        audie.pause();
    else
        audie.play();
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QCGYP/4/

Comment: @user2202031 what does the console say? are there any error raised?

Comment: just to clarify , its playing but when i click again its not pausing

Comment: ran into another problem now when i pause and then try play another song it resumes the other song i paused

Comment: @user2202031 Glad to help. I added `|| audie.src !== audioFile` so that you can change `src`.

Comment: wait coz now the problem is that as soon as i pause a song then try play another song it resumes the previous one its like it cant detect that im trying to play a different song

Comment: @user2202031 See the previous comment, add `|| audie.src !== audioFile` to `if(!audie.src)`. Tested fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/QCGYP/4/

Comment: yeah but now it doesn't pause from the same button

Comment: @user2202031 Well, but there's no problem with my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QCGYP/4/ You can change, play, and pause from both button. Check if your code is the same as mine.

Comment: i Have tried doing the same thing you have on js fiddle it works when using the links of w3 schools however it doesnt work when i use the mp3 files